# Installing RStudio on Mac for the first time. Why can't I install any packages?

Tags: r, installation, install.packages

I've successfully installed RStudio on my Mac after working on a Windows PC for years. Needless to say, package installation is my next step, but whenever I attempt to install a package, an error is returned. The error occurs when I attempt to install package dependencies... for the sake of parsimony, I will use the "tibble" package for this example.

Forgive my novice coding nature, I am still learning each day.

I've tried installing different packages (these are all from CRAN) and the same result occurs each time.

Edit: Entering "no", "yes" (respectively) will install the packages. Does anybody know why I am still receiving this output? It would be great to not have to install packages one at a time. Thanks!

```
> install.packages("tibble")
> y
> y
```

I expect a result of successful installation, but the actual output is as follows:

```
> install.packages("tibble")
also installing the dependencies ‘utf8’, ‘fansi’, ‘pillar’, ‘rlang’


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
       binary source needs_compilation
utf8    1.1.3  1.1.4              TRUE
pillar  1.0.1  1.3.1             FALSE
rlang   0.1.6  0.3.4              TRUE
tibble  1.3.4  2.1.1              TRUE

Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation?
y/n: y
Package which is only available in source form, and may need compilation of
  C/C++/Fortran: ‘fansi’
Do you want to attempt to install these from sources?
y/n: y
installing the source packages ‘utf8’, ‘fansi’, ‘pillar’, ‘rlang’, ‘tibble’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/utf8_1.1.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 218882 bytes (213 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 213 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/fansi_0.4.0.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 266123 bytes (259 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 259 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/pillar_1.3.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 103972 bytes (101 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 101 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/rlang_0.3.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 858992 bytes (838 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 838 KB

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/tibble_2.1.1.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 311836 bytes (304 KB)
==================================================
downloaded 304 KB

Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018i.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘utf8’ ...
** package ‘utf8’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘utf8’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/utf8’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘utf8’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018i.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘fansi’ ...
** package ‘fansi’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘fansi’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/fansi’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘fansi’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018i.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
* installing *source* package ‘rlang’ ...
** package ‘rlang’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘rlang’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rlang’
* restoring previous ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/rlang’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘rlang’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018i.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependencies ‘fansi’, ‘utf8’ are not available for package ‘pillar’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/pillar’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘pillar’ had non-zero exit status
Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
  unknown timezone 'zone/tz/2018i.1.0/zoneinfo/America/New_York'
ERROR: dependencies ‘fansi’, ‘pillar’ are not available for package ‘tibble’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.3/Resources/library/tibble’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tibble’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/sn/zj2b1gqx6wsfs76h5mymrk_r0000gn/T/RtmpqBjXKW/downloaded_packages’
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit the question to make it more readable, see e.g. the [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). In particular, the "code fence" with triple back ticks.

Comment: You should say NO to 'Do you want to install from sources the packages which need compilation?' as your machine appears to not be setup to compile fro source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error messages tell you that Command Line Tools is missing. They provide the software required to compile packages from source (for example, C and C++ compilers).

You can install them using `xcode-select --install` [as described here](http://osxdaily.com/2014/02/12/install-command-line-tools-mac-os-x/) or, as explained in the comments, choose "no" when prompted about compilation from source.